# How to add node attributes next to node name in Python networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, label

I want to draw a bipartite graph connecting colleagues and moviepreferences. How can I show in the graph both the node name (so the moviename or colleague name) and the node attribute (whether it is a colleague or a movie) in the nodes ?

My current code only displays the node attribute and drops the node name.

My code:

```
BG = nx.Graph()
BG.add_nodes_from(employees, bipartite=0, _type='employee')
BG.add_nodes_from(movies, bipartite=1, _type='movie')
edgeinfo = pd.read_csv('Employee_Movie_Choices.txt', sep='\t')
edges = [tuple(x) for x in edgeinfo.values]
BG.add_edges_from(edges)

labels = dict((n,d['_type']) for n,d in BG.nodes(data=True))

%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
pos = nx.spring_layout(BG)
edges = BG.edges()
nx.draw_networkx(BG, pos, edges=edges, labels=labels)
```

If I create label tuples, he gives me an error:

```
BG = nx.Graph()
BG.add_nodes_from(employees, bipartite=0, _type='employee')
BG.add_nodes_from(movies, bipartite=1, _type='movie')
edgeinfo = pd.read_csv('Employee_Movie_Choices.txt', sep='\t')
edges = [tuple(x) for x in edgeinfo.values]
BG.add_edges_from(edges)

labels = dict((n,d['_type']) for n,d in BG.nodes(data=True))  ###ik krijg hier naam movie en employee niet meer bij !!!
labels_new = [(k, v) for k, v in labels.items()]
#labels = [tuple(n,d['_type']) for n, d in BG.nodes(data=True)]
#nx.draw(BG, labels=labels)

%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
pos = nx.spring_layout(BG)
edges = BG.edges()
nx.draw_networkx(BG, pos, edges=edges, labels=labels_new)
```

Error:
---> nx.draw_networkx(BG, pos, edges=edges, labels=labels_new)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 1):

**Why error arises**

From the documentation of [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx)
, `labels` needs to be a dictionary while `labels_new` you fed is a list.

> labels (dictionary, optional (default=None)) – Node labels in a
>   dictionary keyed by node of text labels

From your code,

> labels_new=[(k, v) for k, v in labels.items()]

Thus, the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` arises.

**Workaround: customize the `labels` dictionary**

I do not have the data, but a quick hack can be

```
labels = dict((n, "(" + n + "," + d['_type'] + ")") for n,d in BG.nodes(data=True))
```

#### Demo

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BG = nx.Graph()
employees = [str(i) for i in range(3)]
movies = ["mA", "mB", "mC"]
BG.add_nodes_from(employees, bipartite=0, _type='emp')
BG.add_nodes_from(movies, bipartite=1, _type='mov')
edges = [("0", "mA"), ("0", "mC"), ("1", "mA"),("1", "mB"), ("2", "mA")]
BG.add_edges_from(edges)
labels = dict((n, "(" + n + "," + d['_type'] + ")") for n,d in BG.nodes(data=True))

# Setting up pos for drawing bipartite graph. See the reference for more info
X, Y = bipartite.sets(BG)
pos = dict()
pos.update( (n, (1, i)) for i, n in enumerate(X) ) # put nodes from X at x=1
pos.update( (n, (2, i)) for i, n in enumerate(Y) ) # put nodes from Y at x=2

plt.figure()
edges = BG.edges()
nx.draw_networkx(BG, pos, edges=edges, labels=labels)
```

[image]

**Reference**

[mdml's answer for drawing bipartite graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084004/bipartite-graph-in-networkx)

Comment: This worked ! Thank you very much for helping me out !