# Can I draw a bipartite graph from every dataset?

Tags: networkx, bipartite

I am trying to draw a bipartite graph for my data set, which is like below:

```
source  target  weight
reduce  energy  25
reduce  consumption 25
energy  pennsylvania    4
energy  natural 4
consumption balancing   4
```

the code That I am trying to plot the graph is as below:

```
C_2021 = nx.Graph()
C_2021.add_nodes_from(df_final_2014['source'], bipartite=0)
C_2021.add_nodes_from(df_final_2014['target'], bipartite=1)
edges = df_final_2014[['source', 'target','weight']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
C_2021.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
```

But when I check with the below code whether it is bipartite or not, I get the "False" feedback.

```
nx.is_bipartite(C_2021)
```

Could you please advise what the issue is?

The previous issue is resolved, but when I want to plot the bipartite graph with the below steps, I do not get a proper result. If someone could help me, I will be appreciated it:

```
top_nodes_2021 = set(n for n,d in C_2021.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==0)
top_nodes_2021
```

the output of the above is:

```
{'reduce'}

bottom_nodes_2021 = set(C_2021) - top_nodes_2021
bottom_nodes_2021
```

the output of the above is:

```
{'balancing', 'consumption', 'energy', 'natural', 'pennsylvania '}
```

then plot it by:

```
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(C_2021,top_nodes_2021)
plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
# Pass that layout to nx.draw
nx.draw(C_2021,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color='black',width=0.2,
     edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=True)
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Does this question relate to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084004/bipartite-graph-in-networkx?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me using your code. `nx.is_bipartite(C_2021)` returns true. Check the example below:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = StringIO('''source;target;weight
reduce;energy;25
reduce;consumption;25
energy;pennsylvania ;4
energy;natural;4
consumption;balancing;4
''')

df_final_2014 = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")

C_2021 = nx.Graph()
C_2021.add_nodes_from(df_final_2014['source'], bipartite=0)
C_2021.add_nodes_from(df_final_2014['target'], bipartite=1)
edges = df_final_2014[['source', 'target','weight']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
C_2021.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

nx.is_bipartite(C_2021)
```

Finally to draw them get the bipartite sets. The data you passed during the creation is false (i.g. `bipartite=0` and `bipartite=1`).

Use the following commands:

```
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
top_nodes_2021, bottom_nodes_2021 = bipartite.sets(C_2021)
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(C_2021, top_nodes_2021)

plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
# Pass that layout to nx.draw
nx.draw(C_2021,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color='black',width=0.2,
     edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=True)
```

With the following result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is resolved. but after that, I want to draw the top and bottom nodes from the data to plot the bipartite graph, but for the top nodes, I always get one node which is: {'reduce'}

is this code correct?
top_nodes_2021 = {n for n, d in C_2021.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==0}
top_nodes_2021

Comment: You have got an edge from 'reduce' to 'energy' - so the selection on `d['bipartite']==0` will only return reduce.

Comment: Thank you. could you please advise how I can clean my data set and draw only a bipartite graph? I have deleted the edge from 'reduce' to 'energy'; the output now is {'energy', 'reduce'}. I think I have to do something with my dataset to draw the bipartite graph.

Comment: I do not understand what your goal is in the end. Could you explain it a bit better? If you want to draw the network use: `nx.draw(C_2021)`.

Comment: the issue has been updated. I really appreciated your support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. when I apply this approach to the complete dataset, in return for nx.is_bipartite(C_2021), I got false. Is it confirmed that the graph from the full dataset is not bipartite at all?

Comment: Yes, if nx.is_bipartite() returns false then the graph is not bipartite.